# What is the correct syntax to embed JS from Jquery UI website in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get simple JS to work on my site for testing, but having a hard time with the syntax.

The script I want to enable is simple hide script, html is:

```
<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

JS is:

```
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
});
```

Example is here:

https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

What should I put in JS file to make this work with Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I put in JS file to make this work with Drupal 7?

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    //code starts
    $( document ).click(function() {
      $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
    });
    //code ends

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

See [Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-javascript-and-jquery) for in-depth info.

Comment: Fantastic! So drupal loads both these libraries with core? Jquery and JqueryUI also? So no need to CDN anything or add Jquery files manually ? I use the Jquery update module

Comment: @BrunoVincent correct.